# How do I provide an ECS app permission to write to the disk?

Tags: amazon-iam, grafana, amazon-ecs

I have launched a Grafana Docker container built from source through AWS ECS (Fargate). However, users (including myself) are not able to install Plugins when we log in and we receive the following error:

```
error: "failed to extract plugin archive: could not create \"/var/lib/grafana/plugins/grafana-timestream-datasource\", permission denied, make sure you have write access to plugin dir"
message:"Failed to install plugin"
```

Within our Task we have the following Container definitions:

```
"name": "Custom-App-Container",
"image": "XXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/custom-dashboard-v1:XXXXX",
"cpu": 0,
"portMappings": [
{
    "name": "custom-app-container-3000-tcp",
    "containerPort": 3000,
    "hostPort": 3000,
    "protocol": "tcp",
    "appProtocol": "http"
}
],
"essential": true,
"environment": [],
"environmentFiles": [
    {
       "value": "arn:aws:s3:::custom-app-docker/docker.env",
       "type": "s3"
    }
],
"mountPoints": [
    {
       "sourceVolume": "custom-grafana-plugins-volume",
       "containerPath": "/var/lib/grafana/plugins",
       "readOnly": false
    }
],
"volumesFrom": [],
"logConfiguration": {
"logDriver": "awslogs",
"options": {
    "awslogs-create-group": "true",
    "awslogs-group": "/ecs/Custom-App-Task",
    "awslogs-region": "us-east-1",
    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
 }
```

and Container volumes

```
"name": "custom-grafana-plugins-volume",
"efsVolumeConfiguration": {
    "fileSystemId": "fs-XXXXXXXXXX",
    "rootDirectory": "repos/CustomGrafanaPlugins"
}
```

and added a Task Role called `grafanaTaskRole` with the following Permission policy (AmazonElasticFileSystemClientFullAccess):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "elasticfilesystem:ClientMount",
                "elasticfilesystem:ClientRootAccess",
                "elasticfilesystem:ClientWrite",
                "elasticfilesystem:DescribeMountTargets"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I thought that by setting `mountPoints.readOnly = false` and with the grafanaTaskRole defined (I also tried EC2FullAccess and ECSFullAccess) then the application would have permission to write to the `/var/lib/grafana/plugins` path for installing plugins. I am not sure what other permissions to provide or modify at this point. Thanks!

Comment: Why you need an mountpoint (it looks like an shared filesystem) for plugins at all? Each task container can be independent.

Comment: @JanGaraj if each task was independent, then installing the plugin would only work until the task was restarted/replaced, then the plugin would be gone.

Comment: This is probably a linux file permissions issue on the EFS volume. Are you using an EFS access point? Please show all the EFS configuration settings for your EFS task, and all the configuration settings of the EFS Access point.

Comment: @MarkB  No, you can use env variable `GF_INSTALL_PLUGINS` to install plugins (no UI). Grafana container will install all plugins from `GF_INSTALL_PLUGINS` before start - no need of volume.

Comment: @JanGaraj We're using the mountpoint to include our custom, unsigned plugins, which are built and stored on the EFS source volume (custom-grafana-plugins-volume).

Comment: @MarkB We are not using an EFS access point. I updated the ECS task container definitions with the volume settings.

Comment: I was under the impression that mounting a volume to a container path would allow access to the mounting volume from the container path, but not effect writing to the container path because it's outside of the EFS volume. However, if I remove the mount points and volumes from my ECS task, I can install plugins to the container path (but I don't have access to our custom plugins)

Comment: @AdamRyason `GF_INSTALL_PLUGINS` can install plugin from URL (e.g. S3, GitHub, ...) = no need of volumes (and permission problems, because Grafana uses rootless container).

Comment: "I was under the impression that mounting a volume to a container path would allow access to the mounting volume from the container path, but not effect writing to the container path because it's outside of the EFS volume." I have no idea what you are trying to say here. What is "the container path" in this context? If you try to write to the path the EFS volume is mounted to, then you would absolutely be writing to the EFS volume.

Comment: I highly recommend you add an EFS access point when using EFS with Fargate so you can have an easy way to control the POSIX permissions of the mounted volume.

Comment: @MarkB In this context, container path is `/var/lib/grafana/plugins`, and it was where the EFS was mounted. I thought mounting to that path would have the EFS contents in a sub directory off of `.../plugins` and not effect the `.../plugins` r/w access. With this new insight, I've mounted to `var/lib/grafana/plugins/mnt`, which created a subdirectory that does not conflict with Grafana trying to write to `.../plugins`. Doing this we are able to access our custom plugins and install others from Grafana. I plan to explore using an access point next. Thanks!

Comment: saying `/var/lib/graphana/plugins` is a "container path" doesn't make any sense. The entire file system under `/` is a "container path" from inside the container's perspective. And no when you map an EFS volume to a path, the EFS volume is mounted **at that path** not in a subdirectory.

Comment: I should have been more specific, when I was saying "container path" it was in reference to the `containerPath` variable in our task definition file.